# Is there way to implement something like DataTemplateSelector using XamDataGrid of Infragistics?

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

Is it possible to implement something like DataTemplateSelector using XamDataGrid?
My Datasource is list of different type of objects derived from same base class.
So depending upon type of object i want to dynamically select the template.

If it is possible then which version of Infragistics Wpf dlls provide this functionality.

Thanks..

Comment: If you add the xamdatagrid from the VS toolbox it will add the correct reference/dlls for you.

Comment: I don't think XamDataGrid has any template selection methodology. U can definitely define many templates ans select any DefaultFieldlayout for your grid based on the data source you get.